# Angular UI bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [Angular UI bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)'s datepicker , and when I change programmatically the date the view doesn't change, when I'm in 30 Novembre and I programmatically change the date to 2 December, the date change but the view still fixed in November, here's how I code the next date button.

```
$scope.right=function(){
    if($scope.viewmodel.timeResolution=='yearly')
        $scope.dt.setFullYear($scope.dt.getFullYear()+1);
    else if($scope.viewmodel.timeResolution=='monthly')
        $scope.dt.setMonth($scope.dt.getMonth()+1);
    else if($scope.viewmodel.timeResolution=='daily') {
        $scope.dt.setDate($scope.dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    $scope.changedValue();
};
```

Html :

```
 <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" id="dp" datepicker-mode="mode" init-date="initDate" show-weeks=false max-mode="maxMode"  min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" min-mode="minMode" class="well well-sm"  ng-change="changedValue(viewmodel.dt)"></uib-datepicker>
```

how can I simulate a refresh view everytime I change the date programmatically on the datepicker ?

Comment: can you add the html code for datepicker?

Comment: @azelix  is there business rule to add date? are you try to disable weekend ?

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert again to date. The function set... only returns the timestamp:

```
$scope.right=function(){
    if($scope.viewmodel.timeResolution=='yearly')
        $scope.dt = new Date($scope.dt.setFullYear($scope.dt.getFullYear()+1));
    else if($scope.viewmodel.timeResolution=='monthly')
        $scope.dt = new Date($scope.dt.setMonth($scope.dt.getMonth()+1));
    else if($scope.viewmodel.timeResolution=='daily') {
        $scope.dt = new Date($scope.dt.setDate($scope.dt.getDate() + 1));
    }
    $scope.changedValue();
};
```

Comment: I don't know about your changedValue() function, but the datepicker doesn't need any other call to work.

Comment: You saved me here, your answer is spot on, now it works nicely, and for the changedValue() it does generate Maps and time series i mean by that it dosent have anything to do with the datepicker itself.

Comment: You're welcome. I had some problems with timezone too, using that component, but it can vary according to your backend implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To make your overall experince with angular dates better, you should look into moment .js

http://momentjs.com/

It allows you to create, format, add and subtract dates easily and with minimal issues. Using the default date.set functions can cause a lot of issues.

I have a set up like this using moments with no issues

Comment: It may be an issue i'll look into that later, but that's not the issue i'm having now, the date change as i wanted it there's no problem with the date but the view of my datepicker dosent follow the date when per example the month change from November to December